# Как запустить docker-compose.yml

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, vagrant, docker-compose

Всем привет. Есть vagrant, в котором установлен docker и docker-composer.
Есть файл docker-compose.yml
Как его запустить?

Comment: зайти в папку с docker-compose.yml и написать `docker-compose up`. А что делать с vagrant -  не знаю

Comment: `docker-compose.yml` находится внутри vagrant box или во вне?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно набрать команду docker-compose up

Answer (score 1):

зачем используете вагрант? в линуксе всё нативно работает, а для винды и мака есть Kitematic (работает через виртуалбокс) и офф сборка через Hyper-V виртуализацию https://www.docker.com/community-edition

в хостовой машине можно будет всё запускать не заморачиваясь

```
# запускаем все контейнеры, видим stdout всех контейнеров, а для остановки используем Ctrl+C
docker-compose up
# запуск в режиме демона
docker-compose up -d
# для остановки используем 
docker-compose stop
# для остановки с удалением контейнеров 
docker-compose down
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker-compose up -d
```

запустится в режиме демона.

Чтобы остановить, в папке с docker-compose.yml файлом выполните

```
docker-compose down
```

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию, vagrant прокидывает текущую папку внутрь контейнера.
Можно в контейнере перейти в `/vagrant` и там уже запустить `docker-compose up`